# NavigationController with search, map and table: how to

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

Since I am a newbie in iPhone development, I need some advice on how to structure my xib file in order to get the following (essentially, it should be very similar to **Google Places** app).

I need a **NavigationController** with:

- **Map** with **search** functionality.
- **TableView** with **search** functionality (ideally, the search should be shared between map and TableView).
- One view to show details of a selected item, whatever the source view is (map or table).
- Map view should have a button to show listing view, and viceversa.

My doubt is, what do I have to nest where? I have a **NavigationController** with its **View Controller** set to another class with its own xib, but I don't know how to go on.

Should I create a View with a search bar and another SubView to switch between Map and Table? Or is it better to have two full views each one with its own search bar?

**EDIT 1**

Finally I have decided to implement the following structure:

```
   - TabBarController
       - LugaresNavController (UINavigationController)
           - LugaresViewController (UIViewController)
               - UISearch 
               - SubView (UIView)
               - MapViewController (UIViewController)
               - TableViewController (UITableViewController)
```

`MapViewController` and `TableViewController` have their own **xib** files. What I want is to have the ability to switch between them into `SubView`, but I am not able to do it.

I have assigned `MapViewController` and `TableViewController` file's owner to their respective class in the xib files, and also have specified which xib to load at the attributes of their representation in the xib corresponding to `LugaresViewController`, which is their parent.

When I run the application, all I can see is the TabBar with the NavBar and the UISearch. The frame where `SubView` should render either the map or the table is showing blank...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would create a TableViewController, a ViewController with a mapsubview. each of them got `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *searchString;`which you can then set from the other viewcontrollers

Comment: Are MapViewController and TableViewController children of SubView, and the diagram above is incorrect, or am I misunderstanding the structure?  Is SubView created with a XIB, or programmatically?  UIViews come up blank when not instantiated, a common bug in programmatic creation of views...

Comment: `SubView`, `MapViewController` and `TableViewController` are all represented in the **xib**. They are not children of `SubView` because I cannot nest them on the interface, they just appear at the root level of the xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you are getting your different parent-child hierarchies confused.

To recap:  MVC is Model, View and Controller.

iOS has TWO different parent-child hierarchies:  One for the controllers and one for the views.

The following are part of the controller parent-child hierarchy:

```
- TabBarController
    - LugaresNavController (UINavigationController)
        - LugaresViewController (UIViewController)
```

This means that LugaresViewController.parentViewController should be LugaresNavController and so on.

However the following doesn't make any sense:

```
- SubView (UIView)
    - MapViewController (UIViewController)
    - TableViewController (UITableViewController)
```

Views can have subviews but views can't have subviewcontrollers,

Are you doing the following?

```
- SubView (UIView)
    - MapViewController.view (UIViewController s view is a subview of Subview)
    - TableViewController.view (UITableViewController s view is a subview of Subview)
```

This is a view parent-child hierarchy.  This means that:

1. SubView has two subviews (MapViewController.view and TableViewController.view)
2. MapViewController.parentViewController is nil.
3. MapViewController.navigationController is nil.

you can use view transtions to switch between MapViewController.view & TableViewController.view but not viewController transitions (such as presentModal... or push or pop ViewController...).

If this is what you want, then you just have to make sure that you do:

```
[SubView addSubview: MapViewController.view];
[SubView addSubview: TableViewController.view];
```

Incidentally, SubView is a terrible name.  Usually we call those containerView or something like that.
subview is such an important concept you want to be able to diffrentiate the concept of a subview from the instance of that view.  It's like naming your child "Kid" or your dog "Puppy".

Answer (score 0):

your App is similar to mine, what I've done:

```
- TabBarController
  - TableView
    - SearchBar
    - DetailButton ----\
  - MapView             \____ push ModalViewController
    - SearchBar         /
    - DetailButton ----/
```

now if someone pushes a button in the table view or map view I'm opening the same View but pass other information to initialize it. btw. what is a `LugaresViewController`?

First try only adding a `TableView` and a `MapView` in each tab and look if the nib-binding works well. If not, you're missing something, load nib named or class type. Afterwards you can add the `SearchBarController`'s and provide functionality for that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't really say I agree with your tabbar application. I think a navigation application might work better for this idea. The first view would then have the navigationbar automatically added, with below the UISearchbar, a window, and a normal tabbar.

The UIWindow should contain a subview. That would be either the table, or the map. When you first load the application, and show, say, the table, you'd do:

```
[window addSubview:tableViewController];
```

When you switch to the mapview, you'd do something like:

```
[tableViewController removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:mapViewController];
```

So, for switching views, that's where the UITabBar comes into play. Make sure the tabbar has two segments. Hook up an IBAction to that, which looks a bit like:

```
-(IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged {
   switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex} {
      case 0:
         <call function for removing mapview and adding tableview>

      case 1:
         <call function for removing tableview and adding mapview>

      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

Last but definately not least, which might be the answer to your edit: make sure you've connected all the connectors in Interface Builder (or, if your using XCode 4, just the .xib-file), from the .xib to the File Owner's.

EDIT: Ofcourse, the detail-view for the items pressed on the table/map is pushed in the navigationItem, so the back-button is automatically created and functional in your detailview.

Good luck!